# Error in compiling file using gcc, caused by permission denial

Tags: c++, linux, permissions

I want to compile a `C++` program in `fedora` `Linux`, but the program isn't compiled correctly. I got the following error:

```
"/bin/sh: g++: command not found" make[1]: [*.o] Error 127 make[1]: Leaving directory
```

I would be glad if anyone can help.

Comment: where do you see that permission is denied?

Comment: it seems that sh (the shell) doesn't find the command g++. Are you sure you installed correctly g++?

Answer (score 0):

If you have evidence that permission is being denied (what you don't show, but just assert in the question title), you can check that your mount-point has execution permissions:

```
mount
```

Look for `noexec` flags. To remount:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec {mountpoint}
```

This kind of thing happens more often when building e.g. in `/tmp` or some shared environments